# input type text as floating number with value as 123456.12345 validation: value can be xxx xxx . xxx xx

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" class="bulk" id="bulk_mrcP">
```

maxlength before `.` should be six numbers.

maxlenght after `.` should be five numbers.

This is the piece of code on key press I have written so far and continuing the same.

```
$('input#bulk_mrcP').keypress(function() {

 if($(this).val() > 0)
 {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var valOne = 0;
    var valTwo = 0;

    if(val.indexOf(".") != -1)
    {  
         valOne = val.substring(0,val.indexOf("."));
         if((valOne + '').length > 6)
         {
            var a  = $(this).val(valOne.slice(0, 6));
         }
         console.log(a);
    }           
}
```

});

Any leads on this one would be helpful.

Comment: How about a regex? Check if it matches [/\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,5})?/](https://regex101.com/r/gV4mP6/3)

Comment: @swenzel typo , it should be 5 at the end

Comment: @RoyiNamir yeah you're right. I've updated it.

Comment: @all value as 123456.12345 means six digit before "." and 5 digit post "."

Answer (score 2):

I think this should suffice your requirements...

```
var regx = /^[0-9]{1,6}(\.[0-9]{1,5})?$/;
console.log(regx.test('123456.12345'));  //returns true
console.log(regx.test('1234567.12345')); //returns false
```

Start with a number, accepts minimum of one digit before and after the `.`, allows maximum of six before `.` after maximum of five after `.`

Also note that `.` is optional

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/68spzma9/1/) (borders will change accordingly)

Comment: want to restrict the user max six digit dot max five digit. if he enters 1234567.123456 the value should change to 123456.12345

Comment: @Akki619 that is a wrong user experience in my opinion, I mean you can strip the extra characters but why you should do that? Just show that the input is invalid and user will set it correct.. also you not ceiling or flooring the value, stripping of the character is surely not a good thing

Comment: I agree with you. is there any way i can utilize maxlength as 6 digit dot 5digit

Comment: @Akki619 What do you mean by "utilize"

Comment: I mean to say custom piece of code that will work like maxlength.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate(val, before, after) {
 var v = parseFloat(val).toString().split('.');
 return (v[0].length <= before && v[1].length <= after);
}

console.log(validate(123456.12345, 4, 5));
console.log(validate(123456.12345, 6, 5));
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer please.